# Run java when not installed on machine

Tags: java, git, remote-desktop

I am working on a remote desktop connection. I am not allowed to install anything on it, so I have no access to java, but I need it for a task.

My theory is that I can install java on a network drive, which I can access from my remote desktop and then configure my GIT Bash so it knows where java is.

Is there a way to do this ? Havent found anything useful online....

EDIT: This also means that I can access java from PowerShell / CMD. I am just using GIT Bash most of the time...

Comment: I would get permission to install java on the machine if you need it for the task. Did you try it?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov The system administrator is not very happy about it and doesnt want to. I need a hacker solution :(

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov if that would be a solution I would have already talked to my boss...

Comment: Use a portable version?